# Xcode swift login with Facebook SDK app not loading

Tags: swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I integrated FB in my app and I am able to login with FB without any issues.

When login with FB it is showing option for login from FaceBook app (please see the attached screen shot). Now client wants to open the app without the option.

Unfortunately I am not able to find out the reason. Please help me.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQR2c.jpg)

Comment: which sdk version are you using?

Comment: my sdk version 4.17.0

Answer (score 0):

In order to open Facebook app and redirect, you should handle some schemes listed below.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
  <string>fbapi</string>
  <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
  <string>fbauth2</string>
  <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Comment: yes, i already added these schemes. My issue is app need to login through app without the user selection

Comment: Yes, I understand but you can not manage this behaviour,see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/10/29/Facebook-Login-iOS9/